# Laravel Scout map in toSearchableArray relationship fields

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-scout

Is it possible to map in `toSearchableArray` relationship fields as well. What I mean, having User model I try to search in related model fields as well like;

```
/**
 * Get the indexable data array for the model.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'plz' => $this->account->zip,
    ];
}

/**
 * @return HasOne
 */
public function account(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Member::class);
}
```

In controller searching after results

```
    if($request->has('s')) {
        $founds = User::search($request->get('s'))->get();
    }
```

will throw `Attempt to read property "zip" on null`

I do not really find any infos in documentation related to this question

Answer (score 2):

I do have two ways to do it of which I consider one of them as crude.

#### Method 1:

Here's an example implementation where you're searching all of one model and then a relationship (accounts)

```php
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $array = $this->toArray();

    $array = $this->transform($array);

    $array['country'] = $this->countries->map(function ($data) {
        return $data['name'] ?? '';
    })->toArray();

    return $array;
}
```

#### Method 2:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $array = $this->toArray();
 
        // Customize array...
        $array = [
            'user_name' => $this->user_name,
            'country' => $this->getCountryNameById($this->country_id),
            ...
        ];
 
        return $array;
    }
```

where relationship is defined in helpers or you can make a separate trait and import it in model with method.
Here relationship for country is defined within the model as

```
//Get Country name By id
function getCountryNameById($id) {
    $country = \App\Country::select('name')->find($id);
    return $country->name ?? '';
}
```